# Extract number after particular substring from a flat file

Tags: vbscript

I need to write a VB Script utility for a flat file to find a string `MD*`. If `MD*` is found, find the length of the number which is next to `MD*` and if the length of the number is greater than 10 then replace `MD*` with `XXXXXX*`.

I had written this so far:

```
Dim index,str
str = "MD*"
index = InStr(str, "MD*") + 1
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Test\test.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
If Len(InStr("MD*") + 1) > 9 Then
    strText = Replace(strText, "MD*", "XXXX*")
End If

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Test\test.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strText

objFile.Close
```

Sample Data from the file:

```
NM1*IL*1*GOTODS*NEOL*X***MD*70238
NM1*IL*1*GOTODS*DAVID****MD*19446836789
```

Comment: Are you using vb.net or vbscript? The are very different things. What do you have so far? Can we have a sample set of data from the file, with the expected output?

Comment: Please share some sample data and your desired output. Also, you may be met with some resistance here since it's generally expected that you have written some code, but are having a particular issue with it, as opposed to "Write me a program to do XYZ". This may be simple enough though that someone will cough up a quick routine.

Comment: You have a lot going on here. Try to separate your problem into smaller ones. Can you open a file. Can you read the data from a file. Can you search in a string. Can you get the numbers in a string. Can you count the length of a string. Can you do search/replace. Can you write in a file. All of these are separate problems.

Comment: i am using vbscript , I have below baby steps so far

Comment: @user10265736 That's a good start. Can you edit your question and paste that code in. Highlight after pasting and hit the `{}` and it will preserve the formatting (whitespace and linebreaks). I think still some sample data and desired results would be very helpful here.

Comment: @user10265736 Again, please don't put code or info like this in comments. Edit the question and add the info there. The format is lost in the comments and the linebreaks and whitespace and all that.

Comment: The description for the VBScript tag specifically states "VBScript is not the same thing as VBA or VB.NET. They are three different things so use the correct tags". The description for the VB.NET tag says "DO NOT USE this tag for VB6, VBA or VBScript questions". Please make a point to read all the information provided about how to use the site and also help yourself and us by using ALL the appropriate tags and ONLY the appropriate tags.

Comment: @ ALL : Updated my Question with code and sample data as suggested and kept only one tag VBscript. Bear with me for all these changes since this is my first post. Thank You all for your support .

Comment: To improve this question, and to prevent it from being put on hold, would you be able to explain what _specific_ problem you were having with the code presented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already looks quite good, but I think here you must go through the file line-by-line and check for the `MD*` field.
Looking at the sample data, i believe it is better to check for `*MD*` to make sure none of the other fields end with "MD".

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim objFSO, objFile, strText, lines, i, md, number

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Test\test.txt", ForReading)

' read all text
strText = objFile.ReadAll
' split it into an array of lines on Newline (vbCrLf)
lines = Split(strText, vbCrLf)
objFile.Close

'loop through each line to see if in contains the string "*MD*"
For i = 0 to uBound(lines)
    md = InStr(1, lines(i), "*MD*", vbBinaryCompare )  'use vbTextCompare for case insensitive search
    If md > 0 Then
        number = Trim(Mid(lines(i), md + 4))
        If Len(number) > 9 Then
            'update this line
            lines(i) = Replace(lines(i),"*MD*","*XXXX*")
        End If
    End If
Next

'now write the updated array back to file
'set a different filename here so as not to overwrite your original source file
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Test\test_updated.txt", ForWriting)
For i = 0 to uBound(lines)
    objFile.WriteLine lines(i)
Next
objFile.Close

'clean up objects used
Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO  = Nothing
```

---

**Explanation**

Within the `For i = 0 to uBound(lines)` loop, the first thing to do is to check if the line actually HAS the string value `*MD*`.
The test for this is

```
md = InStr(1, lines(i), "*MD*", vbBinaryCompare)
```

*read about [Instr()](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_instr.asp)*

If the test succeeds, the variable `md` will be greater than 0, so next we try and get the value that is to the right of the `*MD*` string.
Since variable `md` holds the starting position in the string (line(i)), we only have to add 4 (the length of `*MD*`) to that to get the starting position of the value behind it.

According to your examples, there is nothing behind this value in the line, so we can use the `MID()` function to retrieve it, starting from position `md + 4` and not specifying the end position so it will get everything remaining from the line.
This value then is captured in the variable named `number` because it always represents an numeric value with:

```
number = Trim(Mid(lines(i), md + 4))
```

*read about [Mid()](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_mid.asp)*

Because of your comment, I gather that there may be `whitespace` characters like space, tabs and or linefeeds surrounding the value you want, so I have put a `Trim()` around it to eliminate those.

*read about [Trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_trim.asp)*

Mind you: `number` is just a STRING value, but that is what you wanted to test, so we test if the length of this string is greater than 9 with:

```
If Len(number) > 9 Then
```

*look up [Len()](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_len.asp)*

If that is the case, replace the `*MD*` with `*XXXX*` in the line and move on to the next line until we're done.

Hope that helps.

*p.s. I'm not affiliated with w3schools, but for VBScript beginners this is a good place to get info from.*

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot for responding with a beautiful solution. Kudos to you. My First ever post in my life and I got an awesome response within short span of time . Appreciate it @Theo

Comment: After using so far , I had realized that it's replacing the *MD* for the number length less than or = 9 too. Please help .

Comment: @user10265736 Strange, for me it works like expected. Are you sure the input does not contain anything AFTER the last (number) field? Maybe there is a space or extra linefeed there. To overcome that, change `number = Mid(lines(i), md + 4)` into `number = Trim(Mid(lines(i), md + 4))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updated logic. May I know what is the meaning for 
 these lines : Trim(Mid(lines(i), md + 4))  , If Len(number) > 9 Then , lines(i) = Replace(lines(i),"*MI*","*XXXX*") ??? Appreciate your help once again .

Comment: @user10265736 I have added a lot of explaining in the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for wonderful explanation .